# How does regeneration work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plant Respawn Time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44858/plant-respawn-time)

As I understand it ore veins regenerate their ore after 14 game days, but what about other things? I paid for a garden at one of my homes and I picked all the veggies thinking they would grow back. But so far they have not. Do any of the plants grow back? What’s the point of buying a garden that has a one time use, worth a few gold peaces? Also, what about chests? There has been more than one time that I when back into a cave and there was more stuff in the chests. Do they reset after a number of days? Or is it a quest thing?

Comment: And also a duplicate of this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40624/do-chests-and-other-containers-in-dungeons-ever-refill/40628#40628

Comment: That does not answer my questions in the least.

Comment: Which parts do you think are not duplicates?

Comment: Never-mind, I didn't see the Plant link above. I apologize, and thank you for your time.

Comment: No worries! Sorry for the confusion!